# For loop for displace matrix by another one in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

i want to find answers of an inversion problem with below code:

```
E = input('Do you want to calculate by optional beta? (y/n): ')
if E == 'y':
    D = float(input('Please select the Beta constant: '))
    Con  = int(input('Enter the constaraint number: '))
    Beta = np.zeros([len(G)-Con-1, np.size(G,1)], dtype = float)
    dd = np.zeros((len(G)-Con-1, 1))
    d = np.concatenate((d, dd), axis = 0)
    if len(Beta) < len(G):
        Beta[len(Beta)-1,np.size(Beta,1)-2] = D
        Beta[len(Beta)-1,np.size(Beta,1)-1] = (-D)
        for i in range(len(Beta)-1):
            Beta[i,i] = D
            Beta[i,i+1] = (-D)
        G = np.concatenate((G, Beta), axis = 0)
        U, sigma, VT = svd(G,full_matrices = False)
        U = np.matrix(U)
        s = np.matrix(sigma)
        VT  =np.matrix(VT)
        df = pd. DataFrame(sigma, columns = ['Singular Value'])
        Ut = np.transpose(U)
        UT = pd.DataFrame(Ut)
        print('The Transpose of the U: \n' ,UT)
        print('Printing The Singular value: \n' ,df)
        m1 = ((np.transpose(VT)) / s) * ((np.transpose(U).dot(d)))
        m = pd.DataFrame(m1, columns = ['Parameters'])
        print('Printing The Model Parameters m: \n', m)
    else:
        for i in range(len(Beta)):
            Beta[i,i] = D
            Beta[i,i+1] = (-D)
        G = np.concatenate((G, Beta), axis = 0)
        U, sigma, VT = svd(G,full_matrices = False)
        U = np.matrix(U)
        s = np.matrix(sigma)
        VT = np.matrix(VT)
        df = pd. DataFrame(sigma, columns = ['Singular Value'])
        Ut = np.transpose(U)
        UT = pd.DataFrame(Ut)
        print('The Transpose of the U: \n' ,UT)
        print('Printing The Singular value: \n' ,df)
        m1 = ((np.transpose(VT)) / s) * ((np.transpose(U).dot(d)))
        m = pd.DataFrame(m1, columns = ['Parameters'])
        print('Printing The Model Parameters m: \n', m)
elif E == 'n':
    print('We Can code in mode of different value of Beta, But the exercise is to compare with bokk example, so we collet Beta Matrix')
    BetaM = np.matrix(input('Please inser the Betas Matrix: '))
    Con = int(input('Enter the constaraint number: '))
    Beta = np.zeros([len(G)-Con-1, np.size(G,1)], dtype = float)
    dd = np.zeros((len(G)-Con-1, 1))
    d = np.concatenate((d, dd), axis = 0)
    result = np.zeros((BetaM.size , len(G)+1))
    for i in range(BetaM.size):
        D = BetaM[0,i]
        result[i,0] = D
        if len(Beta) < len(G):
            Beta[len(Beta)-1,np.size(Beta,1)-2] = D
            Beta[len(Beta)-1,np.size(Beta,1)-1] = (-D)
            for i in range(len(Beta)-1):
                Beta[i,i] = D
                Beta[i,i+1] = (-D)
            G = ([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6],
                  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6.708],
                  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8.485],
                  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 7.616],
                  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 7],
                  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 7.616]])
            G = np.matrix(G)
            G = np.concatenate((G, Beta), axis = 0)
            U, sigma, VT = svd(G,full_matrices = False)
            U = np.matrix(U)
            s = np.matrix(sigma)
            VT  =np.matrix(VT)
            df = pd. DataFrame(sigma, columns = ['Singular Value'])
            Ut = np.transpose(U)
            UT = pd.DataFrame(Ut)
            m1 = ((np.transpose(VT))/s)*((np.transpose(U).dot(d)))
            T = m1.transpose()
            result[i,1:] = T[0,:]
        else:
            for i in range(len(Beta)):
                Beta[i,i]=D
                Beta[i,i+1]=(-D)
            G = ([[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6],
                  [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6.708],
                  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8.485],
                  [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 7.616],
                  [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 7],
                  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 7.616]])
            G = np.matrix(G)
            G = np.concatenate((G, Beta), axis = 0)
            U, sigma, VT = svd(G,full_matrices = False)
            U = np.matrix(U)
            s = np.matrix(sigma)
            VT  =np.matrix(VT)
            df = pd. DataFrame(sigma, columns = ['Singular Value'])
            Ut = np.transpose(U)
            UT = pd.DataFrame(Ut)
            m1 = ((np.transpose(VT))/s)*((np.transpose(U).dot(d)))
            T = m1.transpose()
            result[i,1:] = T[0,:]
```

in this code i want to save loop results in result matrix for each rotation. but the result is:

```
array([[1.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e-02, 4.61538298e-01, 3.74655664e-01, 3.62071994e-01,
        4.05076514e-01, 2.75069086e-01, 2.49901737e-01],
       [1.00000000e-03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e-04, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e-05, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [6.00000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [5.60000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [5.50000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [5.40000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [5.00000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [4.00000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [1.00000000e-06, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

i used this parameters:

Do you want to calculate by optional beta? (y/n): n
We Can code in mode of different value of Beta, But the exercise is to compare with bokk example, so we collet Beta Matrix
Please inser the Betas Matrix: [[1],[0.1],[0.01],[0.001],[0.0001],[0.00001],[0.000006],[0.0000056],[0.0000055],[0.0000054],[0.000005],[0.000004],[0.000001]]
Enter the constaraint number: 1

can any one help me?